# How to implement shader into UIImageView Swift

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, uiimageview, glsl, shader

Is it possible to attach an 'fsh' file to a UIImageView to create an image with a shader in swift, in the same way that you can attach one to an SKSpriteNode in SpriteKit. If this is not possible, are there any ways to create an SKScene within a UIView to achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: @dfd they are 2 different technologies goined together in a special view called `SKView`.  This is where the `SKScene` gets presented

Comment: `UIViews` do not have access to the GPU,  You pretty much need to have an opengl context setup on a special view, something like EAGL or something i can't remember it has been so long.  `SKView` is a `UIView` that attaches an `SKScene` to it,  this is setup for you in the game template.

Comment: @dfd, I am saying no, you are wrong

Comment: I like to think of it like this,  UIKit are LEGO's, and SpriteKit are KNEX.  There are no way the pieces come together unless you have an adapter to join the 2.  This adapter is called `SKView`

Comment: So how do you use SKView?

Comment: Create a new game project and you will see exactly how it is used

Comment: Yeah i've been trying to do that, but when I implement it into my existing project it gives me a fatal error when running

Comment: Basically I want an SKScene that I can resize within my UIViewController

Comment: you didnt look at the custom class then in the storyboard

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: go into the storyboard file, click on your view, and look at all the settings.  You will see how it works

Comment: Okay so I've made a container view controller, and I want this view controller to create an SKScene. I copied the code from the basic gameviewcontroller file, however I get this error when defining skView:

Comment: Could not cast value of type 'UIView'  to 'SKView'

Comment: you need to learn how a story board works,  this is not a code file.  This sets up your view controller view settings,  Go into the storyboard file and click around

Comment: as in make the UIView in the storyboard file a subclass of SKView?

Comment: yes, that is how you tell the objects in the storyboard what they need to be

Comment: So surely it should work.. :/

Comment: if you correctly set the view you are pulling custom class to SKView yes

Comment: Okay thank you very much.

Comment: @Surge have you considered creating an `SKSpriteNode` with an image and setting the `shader` property?